# left hull-kernel topology

Tags: c-star-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. For each pure state $\tau$ of $A$ defines $N_\tau:=\{a\in A|\tau(a^*a)=0\}$, and denote the collection of all these $N_\tau$ by $\mathcal N$.
For each closed left ideal $L$ of $A$, defines 
$$\vee L:=\{N_\tau\in\mathcal N|L\subset N_\tau\}.$$
Then $\vee A=\emptyset$ and $\vee \{0\}=\mathcal N$, and $\cap_i\vee L_i =\vee {(\overline{\Sigma_i L_i})}$, where $L_i(i\in I)$ is a collection of closed left ideals of $A$.

If for closed left ideals  $L_1$ and $L_2$ of $A$, there is some closed left ideals  $L$ such that  $$(\vee L_1)\cup(\vee L_2)=\vee (L)\tag{1},$$ then $\{\mathcal N\backslash(\vee L)|L \mbox{ is a closed left ideal of }A\}$ forms a topology on $\mathcal N$. And since $$L=\cap \{N_\tau\in \mathcal N|L\subset N_\tau\},$$ we will obtain a bijection between closed left ideals of $A$ and closed set of $\mathcal N$.

> Dose such a closed left ideal $L$ in eq(1) exist?

**My attempt:**
Let $L=L_1L_2$, then $\vee(L)\subset \vee L_1\cup\vee L_2$, but the other direction cannot be verified;
let $L=(L_1:A)L_2$, where $L_1:A=\{a\in A| aA\subset L_1\}$ is the largeset ideal contained in $L_1$, then $\vee(L)\supset \vee L_1\cup\vee L_2$ but another direction cannot be verified either.

Comment: If $A$ is commutative, then these $N_\tau$s are prime ideals and the situation is similar to the Zariski topology of the spectrum of a commutative ring. In this case you may find $\vee(L_1)\cup \vee(L_2)=\vee(L_1\cap L_2)$ (I don't know whether it equals to $\vee(L_1L_2)$, but if so I guess a possible proof perhaps has something to do with $\bigcap_{L\subset N_\tau}N_\tau$, which is an analogue of the radical of an ideal).

Comment: @josephz 1. For communicative case, $N_\tau$($\tau$ is a pure state) correspond to the maximal ideal, so yes it is precisely the restriction of Zariski topology on maximal ideals; 2. In a C*-algebra, $IJ=I \cap J$ where $I$ and $J$ are closed ideals; 3. Do you mean pick   $L=L_1\cap L_2$?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean: If $N_\tau\in\vee(L_1)\cup\vee(L_2)$, then $L_1$ or $L_2\subset N_\tau$, which implies $L_1\cap L_2\subset N_\tau$ and hence $\vee(L_1)\cup\vee(L_2)\subset\vee(L_1\cap L_2)$. Conversely and less trivially, if $L_1\cap L_2\subset N_\tau$, since $N_\tau$ is a prime ideal, then $L_1$ or $L_2$ is contained in $N_\tau$, which shows $N_\tau\in\vee(L_1)\cup\vee(L_2)$. Thus $\vee(L_1)\cup\vee(L_2)=\vee(L_1\cap L_2)$. However I guess the main interest of your problem lies in the noncommutative case, right?

Comment: @josephz right, of course.